# What is going on in ruby's sort method?

Tags: ruby

What do 'a' and 'b' represent in the following code, and how is the `<=>` working?

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
list.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }

#=> [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: @Ryan this question is not just about the spaceship operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `a` and `b` represent a pair of items. It could be any two taken out of your original list. The `<=>` is usually called the spaceship operator. It returns 0 if the two items are equal, -1 if the one on the left is smaller, and 1 if the one on the right is smaller.

There's more info on [the spaceship operator in the Ruby API docs](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Fixnum:%3C%3D%3E). That's the doc for the one on Fixnum since that's what was in your example, but you can check out the definition for Float, String, etc. there as well.

**Updated:** The `sort` function expects the block it's given to follow the same behavior as the spaceship operator. If the first argument, `a` should be sorted first, -1 should be returned; if the second argument, `b` should be sorted first, 1 should be returned; and so on. So in the example of `list.sort { |a,b| a + b }` you're telling sort that the second argument is bigger every time, since `a + b` is greater than 1 for every possible combination in that list. So what you're seeing when you get `[5,3,1,4,2]` is basically an artifact of the order that elements are passed to the block and would likely not be stable across Ruby implementations.

Comment: Usually? First time I hear it called a 'spaceship operator' ;P

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_operator and also the "possible duplicate" link in Ryan's comment on the question.

Comment: Yeah I believe it's called like that. I'm only surprised I didn't encounter it before ;)

Comment: thanks for the answer. i'm aware of `<=>` behaviour in isolation - i just don't understand how this particular block works. for example, why do i get `[5,3,1,4,2]` when i run `list.sort { |a,b| a + b }`?

Comment: Because you're using `sort` wrong. The block is supposed to return -1,0 or 1 just like `<=>` does. In your case it returns always a positive number, so sorting is done in some unexpected way. See: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/Array#sort-instance_method

Comment: @djb, I've added some more info about what `sort` expects its block to do. Does this clear it up?

Comment: @Emily - I am new to ruby and I tried to understand this by looking at the `sort {| a, b | block }` method code. Unable to understand how sort does its work. Can you please help ? Thanks. Source code - http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort. Press magnifying glass on top right corner of method description area.

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer your question backwards:

`<=>` is Ruby's combined comparison operator, and you can use it as short-hand to determine which of the two variables is greater.  In your example, if `b` is greater it will return 1, if `a` is equal to `b` it will return 0, and if `a` is greater it will return -1.

Given that, `list.sort` allows for the inclusion of a [block](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) - that is, an arbitrary piece of code which will replace some default behavior of the function.

This is what you see between the curly braces: `{ |a,b| b <=> a }` is a function, and `a` and `b` are two items from your list which are to be compared. It does this using the body of the function, `b <=> a`, and in this case, sorts the list in descending as opposed to ascending order.

This way, you can have many different ways of sorting items in a list without needing to rewrite the entire sorting function - you only need to supply the section that determines which of two items in the list goes first.

Answer (score -1):

{|a, b| a <=> b} can be thought of "sort a, before b" if "a <= b" ascending 
{|b, a| a <=> b} can be thought of "sort b, before a" if "a <= b" descending